# Jmeter - Regular Expression With variable contents

Tags: jmeter

One of my HTTP response header has the following content (as an example) -->

Set-Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_L0N5YXJhV2ViUG9ydGFs0=-8In3dBVumict4lbSFy8aIkNfMQf1L75qDPmZgb1Gt7CnA8ZDrQ_zeNRB4Hjg0nZrKF8LgHzysJu2Wi8bXIO-s7fAEucytZJ_Q4__Y33_To1; path=/;

I would like to retrieve only whatever is after the = (note between __RequestVerificationToken_  and = sign is variable)

I have added a regular expression Extractor with following information:

Field To Check  --> Response Header

Regular Expression: Set-Cookie:__RequestVerificationToken_.*=(.+?);

Template: $1$

but it doesn't work 
can you please help?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to get the string after `=` and before `;` which will return `-8....To1` so change your regular expression to make sure you hit the first `=` using regex to get all characters without equal sign `[^=]+`, full regex:

```
RequestVerificationToken_([^=]+)=(.+?);
```

and then in Template get group 2 without variable using `$2$`